# What kind of chart is this?

Tags: data-visualization, boxplot

Sorry for the vague question but this chart appears in [Biddle et al. 2009](http://cs.jhu.edu/~sdoshi/jhuisi650/papers/spimacs/SPIMACS_CD/ccsw/p19.pdf) and I've not encountered anything like it before. It's a bar chart with beveled edges, sometimes 'horns'. What do these mean? **Does this type of chart have a name?**

Per https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244083/site-for-asking-about-charts I thought Academia was the best place to ask.

[image]

Comment: You might gain further understanding of the different types of boxplots by using this [link](http://boxplot.tyerslab.com/) that allows you to create boxplots with a built in sample of data or by uploading your own data.

Comment: The top answer to that meta.SE question makes it abundantly clear that questions about charts *do not belong on academia.SE*. I don't know how you could read that post and conclude anything else. That the asker says he's seen people *ask* about charts there doesn't make it on topic there. The question asks where they belong and the top answer addresses that fairly well (though it misses that data viz. is on topic here)

Answer (score 21):

These are notched boxplots. The standard boxplot summarises a distribution in terms of interquartile range (IQR) and median, with 'whiskers' extending to either the full range or some heuristic multiple of IQR after which "outliers" are plotted as points.

The notches show a non-parametric estimate of ~95% confidence intervals of the median. The reference most often given for these is "Variations of boxplots" by McGill, Tukey and Larsen (1978). A recent reference is [Visualizing samples with box plots](http://www.nature.com/nmeth/journal/v11/n2/full/nmeth.2813.html) in *Nature methods*.

Most statistical packages will let you add these as an option when drawing boxplots, for example in R the `boxplot` command has the argument `notch`. Note that there are various subtly different methods of calculating the notches which may vary between implementations.

Comment: Some use "Notched Box Whisker plot", to add the whisker part.